# How to fix the error Cannot change strategy of configuration in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I am receiving the error trying to build the project by Gradle:

gradle -q acRpm

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/anarinsky/eclipse-workspace/aaa/build/gradle-tools/build-scripts/repo-config.gradle' line: 32

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Cannot change strategy of configuration ':fixMe' after it has been resolved.
```

As I understand this problem is specific for gradle version >=3.0.  Yes, this script works at the 2.* version of gradle.  Is there any workaround? I am on MacOs Sierra.

Comment: Too little details, share `build.gradle` file please.

Comment: I will too much time to reproduce it. I just have some doubts about order in which all these is happening. I'm also not sure if `allprojects` can be moved to another file and then applied to root - that might cause some invocation order problems.

Answer (score 7):

The actual reason why I got this error was the `classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:x.x.x'` was bundled via range (i.e. [0.11, 0.99.99]) just like their tutorial says.

Why? Because they made a new version (0.11.0) and had broken everything, so I had to manually specify previous version. This is just infuriating! Spent 4 hours on this.

Comment: It's a pity that I can not upvote my own answer. Faced this issue once again and this NOT UPDATING TO THE LATEST VERSION of this ugly hideous OneSignal plugin is the only working solution