# Incompatible firebase libraries

Tags: android, firebase

I use the latest version of `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3` and the latest version of `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1`. But they depend on the different versions of `com.google.firebase:firebase-iid` dependency (16.0.0 and 17.0.1):

`firebase-core:16.0.3` depends on `firebase-iid:16.0.0`:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:[16.0.1] -> 16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.2] -> 16.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.2.1] -> 16.2.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.2] -> 16.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.0.0
```

`firebase-messaging:17.3.1` depends on `firebase-iid:17.0.1`:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[17.0.1] -> 17.0.1 (*)
```

Therefore android google play services plugin fails with this error: "The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.0.1,17.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.".

Is this a bug? Are there any solutions to fix this problem?

Comment: What is your `com.google.gms:google-services:` *(Google play services plugin from project level Gradle)* version?

Comment: com.google.gms:google-services is `4.1.0`

Comment: when I downgrade this plugin to `3.2.1` it doesn't fail the build, but then android gradle plugin throws an exception: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Android dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid' has different version for the compile (16.0.0) and runtime (17.0.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latest update for firebase-messaging (17.3.2), this update fixes this particular incompatibility issue.

Answer (score 2):

I got similar issue after updating to `com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1`.

I have fixed by adding

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

in app/build.gradle file after apply plugin: `com.google.gms.google-services`.

it looks like this

```
{
    dependencies {
     //......
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the version check implementation.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/15be8218dbb890dbc79deb858addece0ad255831/firebase-installations/customer-lint-checks/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/installations/lint/IncompatibleIidVersionDetector.kt#L98
It seems that the iid version should be 20.1 or higher.

And to find the libraries that need to be updated to update the iid, you can find the firebase libraries that depend on the iid by doing the following:
./gradlew -q app:dependencyInsight --configuration debugCompileClasspath --dependency firebase-iid