# ionic4 firebase notification integration

Tags: firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';

@Injectable()
export class FcmService {

    constructor(private messaging: AngularFireMessaging) {}

    getToken() {
        this.messaging.requestToken
            .subscribe(
                (token) => {
                    alert('Permission granted! Save to the server!' + token);
                },
                (error) => {
                    alert(error);
                },
            );
    }
}
```

and after i build the app and launch it in android i am getting

**FirebaseError: Messaging: this browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)**

Comment: is your device really old?

Comment: its a new one galaxy J6+ Android 9

Comment: I was just guessing to start off with, but from doing some searching it seems that the error has a lot of results

Comment: i was able to fix it using this thread ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839721/the-library-com-google-firebasefirebase-iid-is-being-requested-by-various-other

Comment: Yogesh Patil comment was the only one working for me